# Do not use the system Python 3 version in Vim

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, linux-ubuntu, python

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, which requires the Python 3 system version to be 3.5: updating it to 3.7 breaks the package manager.

At the same time, I want to use Vim with YouCompleteMe. YouCompleteMe [has stopped supporting Python 3.5](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#warning-support-for-python-35-has-ended), and now requires Python 3.7.

If I change system's default `python3` to 3.7 (using `update-alternatives`) YouCompleteMe works but the package manager doesn't; if I keep it at 3.5 it's the other way around.

**How can I have Vim use Python 3.7 while keeping the rest of the system defaulting to 3.5?**

I have tried compiling Vim from source, and using the following configuration, but no luck:

```
./configure \
        --with-features=huge \
        --enable-multibyte \
        --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-command=python3.7 \
        --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3.7-config --configdir) \
        --enable-perlinterp=yes \
        --enable-luainterp=yes \
        --enable-gui=gtk2 \
        --enable-cscope \
        --prefix=/usr/local
```

When running `vim --version` I still see that it is linked against python3.5m:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul 30 2020 11:32:35)
Included patches: 1-1325
Compiled by XXX Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              -perl              +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save    

     system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
     2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
     user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
     system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
     user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
     2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
     defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
     system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
     fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"

Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread
    -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include
    -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
    -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1
    -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12
    -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
    -I/usr/include/freetype2   -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       

Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
    -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/usr/local/lib
    -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0
    -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0
    -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE
    -lm -ltinfo -lelf  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -ldl
    -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lcrypt
    -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm  -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: This probably belongs on another Stack Exchange site. Look into the [`pyenv`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) tool or equivalent. That lets you switch easily between different versions of Python

Comment: @BLayer I considered that, but I thought it might be possible to somehow configure it from vimrc or something similar, so I wanted to give it a shot.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well at least you have a fallback plan.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 will [reach End of Life in April 2021](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), in just 5 months. There are two LTS versions newer than that one available (18.04 and 20.04). There's really no good reason to keep running 16.04 at this point.

Comment: This is for a professional environment, over which I don't have control. I agree the sensible solution is to upgrade the system, but it's out of my power, at least for the short term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile Vim from source to configure which interpreter it should use. The full instructions can be found on the [YouCompleteMe wiki](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source).

It turns out the method described in the original post is correct: configuring the installation with the following options should have Vim link against Python 3.7

```
./configure \
        --enable-python3interp=yes \
        --with-python3-command=python3.7 \
        --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3.7-config --configdir) \
        ... other options
```

The reason this was not happening was that there were leftovers from previous installations/compilations. Cleaning the compilation by running `make clean distclean` and removing any current Vim installations (using `apt` or `dpkg` if they were installed from the repositories or from source using `checkinstall`) should make the following steps work correctly:

```
$ ./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-command=python3.7 \
            --with-python3-config-dir=$(python3.7-config --configdir) \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 \
            --enable-cscope \
            --prefix=/usr/local

$ make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/local/share/vim/vim82
$ sudo checkinstall
```

This is the new result:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jul 30 2020 11:49:11)
Included patches: 1-1325
Compiled by XXXX
Huge version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         +tag_binary
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_old_static
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tag_any_white
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       -tcl
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +termguicolors
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +terminal
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +terminfo
+browse            +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +termresponse
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +num64             +textobjects
+byte_offset       +iconv             +packages          +textprop
+channel           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +timers
+cindent           +ipv6              -perl              +title
+clientserver      +job               +persistent_undo   +toolbar
+clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vartabs
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +virtualedit
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visual
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +visualextra
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +viminfo
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +vreplace
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cursorshape       -lua               +ruby              +wildmenu
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +windows
+diff              +mksession         +signs             +writebackup
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       +X11
+dnd               +mouse             -sound             -xfontset
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +spell             +xim
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         +startuptime       -xpm
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +statusline        +xsmp_interact
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      +xterm_clipboard
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +syntax            -xterm_save

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
   user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
   2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
   user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
   system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
   user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
   2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
   defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
   system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
   fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"

Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread
    -I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include
    -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
    -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1
    -I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng12
    -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0
    -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
    -I/usr/include/freetype2   -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       

Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
    -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic  -L/usr/local/lib
    -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0
    -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0
    -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lSM -lICE -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE
    -lm -ltinfo -lelf  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -ldl
    -L/usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.7m -lcrypt
    -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm  -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have multiple versions of python installed on your system and easily switch between them using `pyenv`

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: I am aware of `pyenv`, and use it to have different Python versions in different projects. However, I don't see how to easily use it for this purpose: Vim (when installed from the repositories) will use the system-wide python3 interpreter. My issue is not with having different Python versions installed, I have 3.5 and 3.7 coexist no problem. How could `pyenv` be used to ensure Vim (and only Vim) uses the 3.7 interpreter when python3 in the system is 3.5?